# MYSQL JSON - extracting part of JSON field using WHERE on its sibling key value

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0, document-store

I'm trying to extract subset of JSON document value based on adjacent key value.

My JSON string:

```
[
  {
    "_metadata": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "_children": [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_metadata": {
      "id": 2
    },
    "_children": [
      "X",
      "Y",
      "Z"
    ]
  }
]
```

Is it possible to return just `[X,Y,Z]` when setting WHERE clause like `$._metadata.id="2"` ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

```sql
SELECT
  `der`.`_children`
FROM
  JSON_TABLE(
    @`json`,
    '$[*]'
    COLUMNS(
      `id` INT PATH '$._metadata.id',
      `_children` JSON PATH '$._children'
    )
  ) `der`
WHERE
  `der`.`id` = 2;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71ffcb5af559cb46f560f4f02ab56ea9).